# Create multiple folders in the working directory

Tags: python, directory

I want to create 20 folders in the working directory. These should have random names containing the current minute, second and hour, plus a random number between 10000 and 50000.

For example, a valid name would be `05_06_20_11050`.

To do that I have the below functions:

```
from random import randint, randrange
from datetime import datetime

def name_generator():
    td = datetime.today()
    e = td.strftime("%m_%d_%y")
    r = randint(51000, 100000)
    s = e + "_" + str(r)
    return s

import os

def directory_creator(name):
    os.mkdir(name)

import os, os.path

def create():
    pa = "C:/Users/Nuru/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/"
    n = directory_count()
    name = name_generator()
    t = os.path.join(pa, name)

    for i in range(n):
        if os.path.exists(t):
            pass
        else:
            directory_creator(name)
```

All the functions work well, except for the `create` function: It only creates one folder. How do I fix this?

Comment: You might want to show `directory_count()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the loop to:

```
for i in range(n):

    name = name_generator()
    t = os.path.join(pa, name)

    if os.path.exists(t):
         pass
    else:
         directory_creator(t)
```